# How to initialize two empty list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to fill out the statement of

> initalise 2 empty list

in `def monster_fight(monster1, monster2)`.

So far I have this.

```
def monster_fight(monster1, monster2):
    # initalise 2 empty list for each monsters attacks that have been used to fight
```

Comment: What is all the rest of this code for? You can't initialize a thing *after* an unconditional `return`, and it's unclear *what* you want to initialize.

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```py
empty_list = []
empty_list2 = list()
```

Comment: Uh, could you maybe decide on one method of creating an empty list ? (since they are equivalent) ;)

Comment: @Programmer: Well, not equivalent if you name-shadow `list`. Which you shouldn't. But regardless, `[]` is generally considered more idiomatic; you've got syntax support that's faster, simpler, and can't be accidentally name-shadowed, why not use it?